# How to detect a cycle in a directed graph using the union-find algorithm

Tags: graph, union-find, cycle-detection

Can I apply the [union-find algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find/) for the detecting a cycle in a **directed** graph other than [Depth First Search (DFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)?

I know that we can apply the union-find algorithm for the detecting cycle in a **undirected** graph.